# Flutter Notifications: Display WhatsApp like notification

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, awesome-notifications

I am trying to display notifications in my flutter app using `awesome_notifications` package (https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) . Below is my code.

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
      id: UniqueKey().hashCode,
      groupKey: message.data["senderUid"],
      channelKey: 'basic_channel',
      title: message.data["title"],
      body: message.data["body"],
      summary: message.data["body"], // Anything you want here
      notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Messaging,
    ),
  );
```

Below is my Json data

```
"message": {
    "token": recieverFcm,
    "data": {
        "title": senderName,
        "body": message,
        "chatRoomId": chatRoomId,
        "sender_profile_pic": senderProfilePic,
        "senderUid": senderUid,
        "click_action": "OPEN_CHAT_ROOM"
    },
    "android": {
        "priority": "high"
    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "category": "OPEN_CHAT_ROOM"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine and I get notifications like below.

[image]

In here it is displaying the first letter of the sender's name as the icon/profile picture. Instead, I would like to display the real photo of the sender. This profile photo is already being sent by the JSON code.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Very late but will answer for other people still looking.

there is largeIcon parameter which takes network image, use this to show image inplace of default circle avatar.

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            var groupName = "Group Name";
            var userName = "UserName";
            var message = "Hiii";
            var image = " add network image link"
            AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
              content: NotificationContent(
                id: UniqueKey().hashCode,
                channelKey: "notifications",
                title: userName,
                body: message,
                summary: groupName,
                payload: {},
                groupKey: groupName,
                largeIcon: image,
                roundedLargeIcon: true,
                notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.MessagingGroup,
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Text("Send"),
        ),
```

Comment: can you please help me take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77994572/6464540, i want to create a notification like this, how do i achieve this with Awesome notification?