# Flutter Customizable Notification

Tags: flutter

please is there a way I can design this type of notification?
a sample code to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please checkout this package :- https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications

Comment: I have, but I seem not to understand how I can use awesome_notification to design the layout of the notification

Comment: check this code it has customisable options  :- https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications#-how-to-show-local-notifications